# Run multiple jmeter scripts parallelly based on the selection of pipeline build with parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I gave a provision to select multiple jmx files from pipline build with parameters in Jenkins.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56kDb.png)

Below is the code that I wrote to get the parameters and pass it to the jmeter script

```
def fileNamesList = Select_JMX_Files.split(',').toList();
def fileValuesList = JmxParams.split(',').toList();
int startIndex = 0
int endIndex = 5
def output = [:]
for(fileName in fileNamesList) {
output.put(fileName,fileValuesList.subList(startIndex,endIndex));
startIndex = endIndex
endIndex = endIndex + 5
}
def result = []
output.eachWithIndex { key, val, i -> str =  "jmeter -n -t ${fileNamesList[i]} -Jthreads=${val[0]} -Jdelay=${val[1]} -Jstart=${val[2]} -Jhold=${val[3]} -Jshutdown=${val[4]} -l out23.jtl" 
result.add("$str".toString())
}   
def parallelStagesMap = result.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}
def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage:jmeterjob") {
            sh "${job}"
        }
    }
}
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "linux1"
          }
    stages {
        stage('parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below is the console output once the job is executed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FYIv.png)

Can you please help me on this where i am missing?

I am new to jenkins and pipeline scripts

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you unless we see the failure reason, and in case of [parallel stages](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) it's not in the console output, you need to go to your project dashboard and hover the mouse over the failed stage:

[image]

It's also possible to [run JMeter tests in parallel via Taurus framework](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests)